# Error while setting icon in taskbar

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I try to set an icon in taskbar using wxWidgets 3.0 on Ubuntu.
My png is hardcoded in `static const unsigned char image_png[]`.

```
wxIcon icon;
icon.CopyFromBitmap(wxBITMAP_PNG_FROM_DATA(image));
wxTaskBarIcon* taskBarIcon;
...
taskBarIcon->setIcon(icon);
```

This code is compiled with no problems though it gives me `gtk/bitmap.cpp(1328): assert "IsOk()" failed in GetPixbuf(): invalid bitmap` which is invoked by `setIcon` function.
Obviously, no icon is shown.
Is there any problem with this piece of code?

Comment: maybe there is some issue with the `wxBITMAP_PNG_FROM_DATA` macro, maybe you could try to create a wxBitmap using [`wxBitmap::NewFromPNGData`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_bitmap.html#a2048897970d5e845040fcfc0259e1be1) and checking it with `wxBitmap::IsOk()`

Comment: I created a wxBitmap using 'wxBitmap::NewFromPNGData' and IsOk() method returned false.
So now I have
'static const unsigned char image_png[] = ...;'
'auto bitmap = wxBitmap::NewFromPNGData(image_png, WXSIZEOF(image_png));'
and 'bitmap.IsOk()' returns 'false'